# вставка html не работает в цикле. JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        $("#pagediv").html('<button onclick="testfunc()" name="pages' + i + '"></button>')
    }
```

В итоге я получаю лишь один элемент в div

```
<div id="pagediv" class="col-md-10 justify-content-center">
<button onclick="testfunc()" name="pages6"></button>
</div>
```

Почему он не вставляет необходимое количество раз. В цикле pages = 7. И да, по факту я получаю последний созданный элемент. Ведь pages6  = это pages + i. Вот оно только и есть. Последний элемент

Comment: Вместо html() используйте append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#pagediv").append('<button onclick="testfunc()" name="pages' + i + '"></button>')`

Comment: очень странно, пробывал - не канало, сейчас заработало.